# Where in RSpec + Factory Girl create app-wide database records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, belongs-to

I've read some topics about not using RSpec's before all callback, but none of those answered my question: I normally got constant-like records in my db. They are not changeable to my users and are required as 'belongs_to' subject in every 'Order' (the most created Model in my app) object. It would feel unnatural for me to create a factory for this model.

So where am I to create those records (most of the time it is just couple of them)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem.  You don't need to use FactoryGirl to create data during testing, it just gives you convenience for when you need to create test data frequently for particular models.  You can simply do a straight `Model.create(attribute: value, ...)` in `before(:all)` for something like this.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean yeah, I understand that, but I really don't need to recreate these values before anything, I want them be always at db. May be it is a question of how to create Db records which would be persist all along the suit run

Comment: Are you using something like `DatabaseCleaner`?  You can configure this to exclude certain tables when it cleans.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean no, I am not and if I would, how am I put the records in the first place? As I know test database is initially recreated from scratch and so is empty

Comment: Sorry, I think I've misunderstood your question - you want to create these records manually, once, in your test database and then never have to worry about them again?  I don't know how you could do this as I've always considered the test database to be transient, and not really guaranteed to be in any specific state between test runs.  Using `before(:all)` or `before(:suite)`, and proper configuration of the database cleaner strategy you can guarantee it's state during the test run but not between runs.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean Yes, it seems to be a consice solution. Quite obvious I think ) but I'm gratefull to you for clearing my doubts. I'd gladly accept your answer if you answer the question instead of comment

Comment: I haven't really answered your question, just pointed you at a couple of things to consider.  Uri's answer gives you another option which may be closer to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could populate your test db using

```
rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test
```

before running your tests the first time, after that they will be available for every run. Be careful though not to change the test db during the tests, to avoid polluting your seed data.